# How can I consume only 1 message from RabbitMQ (Python)

Tags: python, rabbitmq

I would like to use RabbitMQ for my batch process.
One task(container) gets one message from RabbitMQ. Then the task(container) complete and never do again.

For the first time, I used a script (Docker CMD) and get the input by reading as following.

Dockerfile:     `CMD /usr/bin/amqp-consume --url=$BROKER_URL -q $QUEUE -c 1 /app/worker.py`

worker.py:     `sampleName = sys.stdin.readlines()[0]`

However, this approach waits infinitely if there is no message from a queue.

Accordingly, I used a python script to consume one message.

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python
import pika
import sys
import time

connection = pika.BlockingConnection(
    pika.ConnectionParameters(host='localhost'))
channel = connection.channel()

channel.queue_declare(queue='task_queue', durable=True)
print(' [*] Waiting for messages. To exit press CTRL+C')


def callback(ch, method, properties, body):
    print(" [x] Received %r" % body)
    sampleName = body

    ## Working script -- Start

    ## Working script -- End

    print(" [x] Done")
    ch.basic_ack(delivery_tag=method.delivery_tag)
    sys.exit(1)

channel.basic_qos(prefetch_count=1)
channel.basic_consume(queue='task_queue', on_message_callback=callback)

channel.start_consuming()
```

But I still questionable. 
(1) Is it consume only one message? 
(2) If there is no message in the queue, how can I exit the script?
(3) I ack to RabbitMQ when I finished the task. But the task might take around 7 hours. I will execute more than 200 tasks at once. Is it stable to keep connected?

Comment: What is the reason for this approach over an already existing solution such as [celery](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/getting-started/introduction.html)?

Comment: Can you kindly show some examples of celery for the work?

Comment: My examples would not be any better than the numerous ones in the documentation